# jQuery 2.1.4 issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I added an autocomplete field to a view and it works just fine until I make a selection then I get an error in this function:

```
 // Support: Android 2.3
 // Workaround failure to string-cast null input
 jQuery.parseJSON = function( data ) {
      return JSON.parse(data + "");
 };
```

It says there is an invalid character.  If I change it to this, I don't get an error:

```
     // Support: Android 2.3
     // Workaround failure to string-cast null input
     jQuery.parseJSON = function( data ) {
         if (data !== undefined)
             return JSON.parse(data + "");
         else
             return null;
     };
```

Is there something I am missing here?  My code is simple and have used it in numerous views:

```
 <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.State)&nbsp
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.State, new { id = "txtState", style = "width:50px"})
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Zip)&nbsp
                            @Html.TextBoxForWithTitle(x=>x.Zip, new { id = "txtZip", style = "width:50px"})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

JS:

```
 $("#txtState").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 'data': request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStates")',
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (obj) {
                        return {
                            value: obj.Text,
                            label: obj.Value
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        open: function () {
            $("#txtState").autocomplete("widget").width(150);
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var test = ui.item.value;
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        $("#txtState").autocomplete('search', $("#txtState").val());
    }).blur(function () {
        var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
        keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
        $(this).trigger(keyEvent);
        if (neworold != "old") {
            $("#txtState").val($("#txtState").val());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just wondering, same issue on other jQuery version? If ya, your title is quite unrelevant

Comment: This is the version I've had this problem with.